# Convert json string to value

Tags: c#, jquery, json, json.net

I have two json string and also posted here. First json string convert from c# data table using newtonsoft dll. The second one is manual string. If i use the second string means chart displayed well. First one means chart not displayed. I just found the error "value" and "y" like a string in first json string. Kindly help me to change the first one to second one.

```
1)
[
  {
    "name": "CHE-CORPORATE",
    "value": "42",
    "y": "11.8"
  },
  {
    "name": "CHE-TELUGU",
    "value": "123",
    "y": "10.8"
  },
  {
    "name": "CHE-MALAYALAM",
    "value": "13",
    "y": "23.8"
  }
]

2)
[
  { "name": "CHE-TELUGU",
    "value": 123,
    "y": 10.8 
  },
  { 
    "name": "CHE-CORPORATE",
    "value": 45,
    "y": 40.8
  }, 
  { 
     "name": "CHE-MALAYALAM",
     "value": 155,
     "y": 12.8 
  }
 ]
```

Comment: simply convert the string to int ... and if it doesn't help, post your chart code

Comment: Change your DataTable columns for "value" and "y" to `int` and `decimal` respectively

Comment: I applied this json string to chart data.

Comment: can add you query how you getting data from table ?

Comment: Thank you so much i got it. I changed the datatable datatype. Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the string to number

```
$.each(data,function(key,val){

    val.value=+val.value; // convert the string to number
    val.y=+val.y;

});
console.log(data);
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qS9jc/1/)